React DevTools Warning and CORS Error in Spring Boot & React Application
I'm working on a project that uses Spring Boot for the backend and React for the frontend. I'm encountering a couple of issues that I'm unsure how to resolve:

React DevTools Warning: I'm getting the following warning in the console:


Selector unknown returned the root state when called. This can lead to
unnecessary rerenders. Selectors that return the entire state are
almost certainly a mistake, as they will cause a rerender whenever
anything in state changes.


CORS Policy Error: When attempting to make a request from my React frontend to the Spring Boot backend, I'm running into a CORS issue:


Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.1.33:5001/login'
(redirected from 'http://localhost:5000/api/user/profile') from origin
'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
resource.

I have configured CORS in my Spring Boot application, but I'm still getting this error.

For the CORS Error:

I added a CORS configuration to my Spring Boot backend to allow requests from "http://localhost:3000", which is where my React app is running. The configuration is as follows:
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.sessionManagement(managment -> managment.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(
                        Authorize -> Authorize.requestMatchers("/api/**").authenticated().anyRequest().permitAll())
                .addFilterBefore(new JwtTokenValidator(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()))
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());

        return httpSecurity.build();
    }

    private CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {

        return new CorsConfigurationSource() {

            @Override
            public CorsConfiguration getCorsConfiguration(HttpServletRequest request) {
                CorsConfiguration cfg = new CorsConfiguration();
                cfg.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:3000"));
                cfg.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "HEAD"));
                cfg.setAllowCredentials(true);
                cfg.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
                cfg.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization"));
                cfg.setMaxAge(3600L);
                return cfg;
            }
        };
    }
    

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}

What I expected:
For the CORS Error I expected the requests from my React frontend to be allowed by the Spring Boot backend without any CORS issues, especially after adding the CORS configuration. I anticipated that the CORS configuration would handle the cross-origin requests, but it seems like something might be missing or incorrectly configured.

its quite clear you have not read the docs before asking. Handing out JWTs to browsers is not recommended so you have built some home made JwtTokenValidator, which is home made security, it is dangerous. Also your implementation does not follow the recommended way of implementing CORS in the docs. Read the docs, and remove the dangerous login and implement one of the pre implemented login already existing in spring security. Why pull in a security framework if you dont intend to use it https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/integrations/cors.html

Try giving origin in the cors configuration,
in Express or Nest JS we do as follows:
cors({
origin:"http://localhost:3000"
})
